# window.screen.orientation does not work in angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Getting following error when I try to lock the screen orientation,

`Property 'lockOrientation' does not exist on type 'Screen'`

**Angular 4 code**

```
var lockFunction =  window.screen.lockOrientation || window.screen.mozLockOrientation || window.screen.msLockOrientation || window.screen.orientation;
```

The same works with the following **JQuery code**

```
var lockFunction =  window.screen.orientation.lock;
if($.isFunction(lockFunction)){
    lockFunction.call(window.screen.orientation, 'landscape');
}
```

It is a native web app, not trying with ionic or PhoneGap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OP: Please use the [tag:angularjs] tag for version 1.x only, for 2+ use the [tag:angular] tag (Already edited out that tag). Thanks :)

Comment: I may be missing something but why does the error say 'Screen' with a capitol 'S' not not a lowercase like in your example?

Comment: Have tried with both capital and small case. No luck. I think the error message format is so..